# No route matches {:action=>“show”, :controller=>“”}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, action, runtime-error, show

I am getting a `No route matches {:action=>“show”, :controller=>“predictions”}` error but do not understand why. I am guessing it could be something to do with my model relationships and I may need to add a route.

Prediction Model

```
class Prediction < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :fixture_id, :predicted_result
  has_one :fixtures, :class_name => 'Fixture', :foreign_key => :fixture_id
  belongs_to :fixture
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Prediction Controller

```
class PredictionsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /predictions
  # GET /predictions.json
  def index
    @predictions = Prediction.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @predictions }
    end
  end

  # GET /predictions/1
  # GET /predictions/1.json
  def show
    @prediction = Prediction.find(params[:id])
    @fixture = Fixture.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @prediction }
    end
  end

  # GET /predictions/new
  # GET /predictions/new.json
  def new
    @prediction = Prediction.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @prediction }
    end
  end

  # GET /predictions/1/edit
  def edit
    @prediction = Prediction.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /predictions
  # POST /predictions.json
  def create
    @prediction = Prediction.new(params[:prediction])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @prediction.save
        format.html { redirect_to @prediction, notice: 'Prediction was successfully     created.' }
        format.json { render json: @prediction, status: :created, location: @prediction }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @prediction.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /predictions/1
  # PUT /predictions/1.json
  def update
    @prediction = Prediction.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @prediction.update_attributes(params[:prediction])
        format.html { redirect_to @prediction, notice: 'Prediction was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @prediction.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /predictions/1
  # DELETE /predictions/1.json
  def destroy
    @prediction = Prediction.find(params[:id])
    @prediction.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to predictions_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Show View

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Fixture:</b>
  <%= @prediction.fixture_id %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Predicted result:</b>
  <%= @prediction.predicted_result %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_prediction_path(@prediction) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', predictions_path %>


>rake routes
      users_new GET    /users/new(.:format)            users#new
    predictions GET    /predictions(.:format)          predictions#index
                POST   /predictions(.:format)          predictions#create
 new_prediction GET    /predictions/new(.:format)      predictions#new
edit_prediction GET    /predictions/:id/edit(.:format) predictions#edit
     prediction GET    /predictions/:id(.:format)      predictions#show
                PUT    /predictions/:id(.:format)      predictions#update
                DELETE /predictions/:id(.:format)      predictions#destroy
       fixtures GET    /fixtures(.:format)             fixtures#index
                POST   /fixtures(.:format)             fixtures#create
    new_fixture GET    /fixtures/new(.:format)         fixtures#new
   edit_fixture GET    /fixtures/:id/edit(.:format)    fixtures#edit
        fixture GET    /fixtures/:id(.:format)         fixtures#show
                PUT    /fixtures/:id(.:format)         fixtures#update
                DELETE /fixtures/:id(.:format)         fixtures#destroy
          teams GET    /teams(.:format)                teams#index
                POST   /teams(.:format)                teams#create
       new_team GET    /teams/new(.:format)            teams#new
      edit_team GET    /teams/:id/edit(.:format)       teams#edit
           team GET    /teams/:id(.:format)            teams#show
                PUT    /teams/:id(.:format)            teams#update
                DELETE /teams/:id(.:format)            teams#destroy
          users GET    /users(.:format)                users#index
                POST   /users(.:format)                users#create
       new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)            users#new
      edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)       users#edit
           user GET    /users/:id(.:format)            users#show
                PUT    /users/:id(.:format)            users#update
                DELETE /users/:id(.:format)            users#destroy
           root        /                               fixtures#index
```

Comment: Can you add your routes.rb?

Comment: Important missing detail: OP is visiting `/predictions` and gets the error about show rather than the index page. `/predictions/1` *does* work.

Comment: can u post your error trace

Answer (score 0):

Routes (`config/routes.rb`) should probably include:

```
resources :users
resources :predictions
resources :fixtures
```

Type `rake routes` at the command line (from the root directory of the application) to see what routes you have.

Initially, change:

```
def show
    @prediction = Prediction.find(params[:id])
    @fixture = Fixture.find(params[:id])  
    # Note: for fixture, the id would be different, prob fixture_id
```

to

```
def show
    @prediction = Prediction.find(params[:id])
```

i.e. remove the fixture.  You can always use the relationship to show it in the view, i.e. `@prediction.fixture_id` or `@prediction.fixture.name`

Comment: I have all those routes included already, thats why I am confused

Comment: Please type `rake routes`, what do you get for output? Thanks

Comment: I removed the @fixture from the predictions controller, but I still see the routes error. Unfortunately I can paste what I see as I am limited for characters but I do see all my models listed when I run rake routes if that helps?

Comment: Which LINE is the error on.  Please provide the stack trace of the exact error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would be causing the error, but in your model file

```
has_one :fixtures, :class_name => 'Fixture', :foreign_key => :fixture_id
```

should be just:

```
has_one :fixture
```

Always a good hint: has_one = singular, has_many = plural